# Telegraf - send Error/0/false if input plugin (service) is down

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I need calculate my service uptime (e.g redis, memcached)

`= success fetching metrics attempts / *total* fetching metrics attempts (every 10 sec for some period)`

Can I somehow configure Telegraf to send 0/false if my input (service) is down?
Cause now if input-service is down influxdb don't receive any new metrics points from telegraf (only error logs on telegraf daemon side).

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Nelson answered here https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4563#issuecomment-413653844

that each plugin can add custom metrics to `internal` plugin (example: http_listener input plugin)